# Replace text with link in PHP

Tags: php

I've been trying to replace text after a specific symbol with a link.
For example:
If I have "bla bla bla @Name bla bla bla", I want to be able to just single out the 'Name' (following the symbol '@') so I can append on `<a></a>` tags to it to link a profile.  I've tried several approaches but no luck so far.

My latest attempt:

```
$content= $c->content;
if ($text = explode('@', $content, 2)[1]){
    $ref_id = getIdByUser($text, $db);
    $new_text = "<a href = 'profile.php?id=$ref_id'>".$text."</a>";
    $rep_string = str_replace($text, $new_text, $content);
    echo $rep_string;
} else {
    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: _several approaches_ you say?

Comment: Would you like to share these approaches with us

Comment: My apologies, I Just edited in my latest (and closest) attempt.

Comment: Will it always be `@Name` or could that be `@Spike` or `@Fred`

Comment: I'm using @Name as a placeholder example.  I want the script to see the @, and then store the name that follows as a variable so I can edit/use it further.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback), with the `use($db)` to call `getIdByUser()` inside the callback.

```
$content = "bla bla bla @Name bla bla bla" ;
$rep_string = preg_replace_callback('~@(\w+)~', function($matches) use ($db) {
    $text = $matches[1]; // here, $text is "Name"
    $ref_id = getIdByUser($text, $db);
    return "<a href='profile.php?id=$ref_id'>$text</a>";
}, $content);
echo $rep_string;
```

Outputs something like:

```
bla bla bla <a href='profile.php?id=2'>Name</a> bla bla bla
```

Comment: @SpikeedooG You need to keep the `@` in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `regexp` and `preg_replace()` solve your problem. I.e. `preg_replace('/\b@(\S+)\b/', '<a href="something.php?nick=$1">$1</a>', $text)`.

Regexp is powerful tool and PHP manual has great chapter about it.